# DRY'ing up rails app with a new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm learning Rails by doing an app for a college project that is basically a SO copy. Consider the following routes:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :answers
  post :vote_up, :vote_down, :on => :member
end

resources :answers do
  post :vote_up, :vote_down, :on => :member
end
```

While this works fine, I'm sure it isn't the best way to do it. I got a lot of duplicated code between the `vote_up` and `vote_down` actions on both controllers. My specs have a lot of duplication too.

I would like to know how can I approach this in the most DRY way possible. I guess a `VotesController` is needed, but I played around with routing and didn't get a practical solution. All I got was some big URL's and not what I really hoped.

Can you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: I'm sure the world and their dog are implementing an SO clone at the moment, if you want to take the same basis and produce something a bit more entertaining that you and your friends can run a site with, you might go for a classic Q&A site ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q&A_website ) in the Forum 2000/Conversatron mould. Those were pretty funny and nobody seems to be doing that any more...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. An SO clone seemed like a nice idea at the time. But it is strictly for the specific class that I'm taking. Unfortunately I've committed a lot of time to change it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing a `vote_controller` which can take a vote in either direction, rather than splitting out up and down into their own controllers.

The question to ask as regards splitting the up and down vote into its own controller is how different they are. If you had a `vote_up` and `vote_down` controller both of them would have to find the votes of the entity being voted on, add a new vote and then store the data. Almost everything there would be the same whether or not you are voting up or down. In fact, the way I would manage votes would be to have a `vote` type a little like this:

```
   class Vote
        attr_reader :direction, :user, :timestamp
   end
```

That way a single vote type can record whether it is an up or down vote as well as recording who made the vote ( so if someone is trolling you can undo all their work at a go ) and the time the vote was made, which is always useful.

Then when you call `vote_controller.up_vote` you create a new `Vote` object with a positive direction, for `vote_controller.down_vote` you create one with a negative direction. Everything else is totally common, so all you would have in the vote controller would be vaguely like this:

```
def vote(direction)
    myVote = vote.new(direction, Request.userId, Time.now )
    voteOnObject.votes.add(myVote)
end

def up_vote
    vote( 1 )
end

def down_vote
    vote( -1 )
end
```

You will notice that this is nothing like working code. That is partly because I don't want to do your homework for you, partly because I haven't done much Ruby lately, so I'm a little creaky. The important thing is the principle here.

If you want to be *properly* DRY you would also design this in a way that the same vote controls could be attached to questions, answers, comments and so on ( so they have a parent object of a given type/implementing a given mixin whose votes they adjust rather than affecting a model level vote object ) without having to make any changes.

Comment: This certainly looks like the right way to pursue. Since I'm pretty new at rails, but ruby as well, I'll have to look more into mixins.

Comment: Would splitting out the up and down votes into controllers be a viable option too?

Comment: Mixins are a way of managing multiple inheritance. You may find that voting itself could be a mixin you could incorporate into different controllers to provide the same functionality to all of them, but bear in mind that this is core Ruby functionality and the current version of Rails probably has an elegant way of handling this as its not an uncommon scenario and the people who write Rails are _smart._

Comment: I gained more understanding on the principle with your edit. Thanks for taking the time to explain it more. I will follow this direction.